# AJAX call using HTTP 1.1

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis-7.5

We have one of our sites hosted externally, and all of our internet access is through a proxy.

We've found that this remote site (ASP.NET 4.0, IIS 7.5, Server 2008 R2) doesn't work on most of our domain machines due to the "Use HTTP 1.1 through proxy connections" setting not being set in IE9 - the ScriptResource.axd pages get garbled and come out as illegible characters. (WebResource.axd and all other calls are fine).

We can fix this internally, but are worried that other users may have the same problem, so my question is: is there a setting that controls how ScriptResource.axd is served by IIS that we can change to alleviate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the the 64-bit ScriptResource.axd handler was sending compressed data whether the browser could handle it or not.

The fix was to add this to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
</system.webServer>
```